# FileMaker, Field Options: Difference between Data and Calculated Value

Tags: database, macos, filemaker

In FileMaker, are there any subtle differences between the two settings bellow? My colleague says he once experienced that these two options behave differently in practice but he cannot remember the details. Are there any special situations where one would be preferable over the other?

I see that the "Do not replace existing value..." setting would make a difference, but assuming that this is off, are they the same?

I've done a Google search and have also read this document: http://www.filemaker.com/help/13/fmp/en/html/create_db.8.23.html

I'm using FileMaker 11.

**Option 1:**
[image: Option 1]

**Option 2:**
[image: Option 2]

Comment: This question is not about programming. I recommend you join of the forums dedicated to the FileMaker platform and ask questions of this type there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value in the Data property is only used on record creation, while the calculated value is used:

1. On record creation if there is nothing in the Data property (they can be combined)
2. If the field is empty and any referenced fields are changed.
3. If the "Do not replace existing value" is unchecked and any local referenced field is changed .

Comment: This is not related to OP data in the screenshot. He does not reference any fields in calculations, so after the record creation the calculation will never be triggered again, which is exactly the same as Data entry.

Comment: Was the downvote really necessary? The OP asks for differences between these two methods and I explained them. Besides, he has accepted my answer as the preferred answer. Fwiw, you have specific mistakes about the "Do not replace existing value" in your answer and I didn't downvote you.

Comment: OK, I got to emotional about it. Edit your answer, so I can remove downvote.

Comment: My answer is related to the exact setup of the OP, the same as his screenshots. Last paragraph explicitly states that the answer relates to calculation using a literal value. You and Michael can argue that the question was more generic and the example was a bit unfortunate, I appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is any difference between the two. I used both and did not see any difference in behaviour.

I would imagine, the calculation is a bit slower, but unless you are generating millions of records at a time, you will not see any difference.

In calculation, checking "Do not replace existing value" should not make any difference either. Checked or unchecked it will only be triggered on the record creation.

Obviously we are talking about the case where you set both to literal values. The calculated value is different as you can insert a calculation, such as current date.

Comment: "*Checked or unchecked it will only be triggered on the record creation.*" No. If unchecked, the calculation will be re-evaluated every time the field is modified.

Comment: That's what I thought, but it looks like if you set Auto calc to literal it will ignore any field changes. I did the same setup as the OP and I can overwrite or clear the field with Do not replace existing value unchecked. Tried on 13 and 15.